# MAGENTO - Load last created Product to Cart

Tags: magento, cart

is it possible to load the last registered (created) Product in my Cart?
How?

I know it sounds crazy but i need this for one of my project.

I think this is the part where the Product gets loaded:

cartcontroller.php

```
/**
 * Initialize product instance from request data
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product || false
 */
protected function _initProduct()
{
    $productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
    if ($productId) {
        $product = Mage::getSingelton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems()
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($productId);
        if ($product->getId()) {
            return $product;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This (if I´m right) i need to be replaced with the last in shop created Product - sound weired but i need this....

Answer (score 1):

You can get the items in the cart like this:

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
```

Then loop through the items and see which one has the biggest id.

```
$max = 0;
$lastItem = null;
foreach ($items as $item){
    if ($item->getId() > $max) {
        $max = $item->getId();
        $lastItem = $item;
    }
}
if ($lastItem){
    //do something with $lastItem
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - but thats not exact what I tried to do - iI changed my text on Top to be more specific.

If a User adds a Product to Cart - i need to show the last in shop created Product in cart insted of the choosen one - i know it dont makes sense to you but i need this for some calculations.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there - try this code:

```
$collection = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->order('created_at DESC');
$latestItem = $collection->getLastItem();
```

Note that when you get the latest quote item, you're not actually obtaining the product. To get the actual product, you would need to add this line:

```
$product = $latestItem->getProduct();
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage::getSingelton() :-/ am I missing something? Sorry but I´m very new in it ...

But i think u didn´t get my point:

If a User adds a Product to Cart - i need to show the last IN SHOP created Product in cart insted of the choosen one - i know it dont makes sense to you but i need this for some calculations.