# Magento get last product added to cart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento

i need to get the last product added to cart, with all informations: image, name, sku and custom options if product is configurable. I try with this code but is not working. My Magento version is 1.9.1

```
                 $xitems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    $max = 0;
    $lastItem = null;
    foreach ($xitems as $xitem){
        if ($xitem->getId() > $max) {
            $max = $xitem->getId();
            $lastItem = $xitem;
        }
    }
    if ($lastItem){
        $_xproduct = $lastItem->getProduct();
        $xproductsku = $_xproduct->getSku();
       $xproductname = $_xproduct->getName();               
       $xproductqty = $_xproduct->getQty();  
       $xproductprice = $_xproduct->getPrice();   
       $xproducturl = $_xproduct->getUrl();
    }

                $xhtml .='<a href="'.$lastItem->getUrl().'" title="'.$lastItem->getName().'" class="product-image"><img src="'. Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($lastItem->getProduct(), 'thumbnail').'" width="50" height="50" alt="" /></a>';
                $xhtml .='<a class="item-name" href="'.$lastItem->getUrl().'">'.$lastItem->getName().'</a> <span class="item-price"><span class="price">$'.$lastItem->getPrice().'</span></span>';

        $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxminicart/response')                                         
                ->setMessage($xhtml);
        //append updated blocks
        $_response->addUpdatedBlocks($_response);
        $_response->send();
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can I know the purpose? You can get it by creating a cart object and fetching the cart items. But it's depends on the session.

Comment: Hi Grish, all i need is to get all this information for an ajax popup, so when you add a product in cart, this popup will show what product you add in cart, instead the default text, you add a %s in cart, I want to show entire product information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
        $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        $max = 0;
        $lastItem = null;
        foreach ($items as $item){
            if ($item->getId() > $max) {
                $max = $item->getId();
                $lastItem = $item;
            }
        }
        if ($lastItem){
            $_product = $lastItem->getProduct();
            $xproductsku = $_product->getSku();
           $xproductname = $_product->getName();               
           $xproductqty = $_product->getQty();  
           $xproductprice = $_product->getPrice();   
           $xproducturl = $_product->getUrl();
        }
```

This works..
Say thanks to **Marius**

Reference - [MAGENTO - Load last created Product to Cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170724/magento-load-last-created-product-to-cart)

Comment: is the same thing like what I have there, there in the $xhtml this get all products in cart not last one

Comment: so i need to get there only the last product all details: base image, name, price, url, color, size ... for simple or configurable product

Comment: sorry the code show image of all associated simple product in configurable

Comment: is a problem with image for configurable products, do you know what is it?

Comment: Sure, What exactly you want? Let me try in my local.

Comment: please test this for configurable product, and add it in cart for many times

Comment: so Girish I want to tell you again the idea, so when a customer press Add to Cart button, I want to show this product in a popup ... is okay what we do here? I think is about the actual product not the last, I am right?

Comment: Yes it is correct. for image problem go here : `admin->system->config->sales->checkout->Shopping Cart`

Comment: is there any way to talk on skype? i want you to look there if you want to help me, thank you

Comment: I think I know where is the problem, when refresh the page everything is working fine, I update that minicart with ajax ... do you have any idea?

Answer (score 5):

The problem with `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastAddedProductId(true);` that the `true` will unset the data.

This:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
   ->getQuote()
   ->getItemsCollection()
   ->getLastItem()
   ->getProduct();
```

should also work.

Comment: this looks like a better implementation compared to the accepted answer

Comment: Agree with comment above. This answer should have been accepted

Comment: Works mostly, but keep in mind this does not work if the product has already been added to the cart before (e.g. qty was increased from 1 to 2). Let's say I have product A and B in the cart, with B being added last. Then I add another unit of product A to the cart, this code will return product B being added last.